# How can i change flat file source component output data type?

Tags: ssis

I'm beginner in `ssis` , i have a flat file source component,want to change error output datatype,but get this error:

```
Error at First Step PACK [Flat File Source [141]]: The data type for "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Error Output]" cannot be modified in the error "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Error Output].Columns[Flat File Source Error Output Column]".

Error at First Step PACK [Flat File Source [141]]: Attempt to set the data type properties on "Flat File Source" failed with error code 0xC020400B. The error occurred while attempting to set one or more of the data type properties of the output column.
```

my screen is this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue comes with DT_NTEXT data type if possible  change data to DT_TEXT.

Work around delete flat file source and create another (make sure metadata is correct).